# Запуск приложения с кешем в зависимости от пользователя

Tags: cmd, bat

прошу помочь с реализацией запуска приложения app.exe.
Данные: есть пользователь user1 и user2, в зависимости от того, кто работает в системе присвоить значение cash1 или cash2 соответсвенно в 4й строке параметру "VerifyCash = " файла app.config и запустить приложение app.exe

```html
CLS
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 1251
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET uname=%username%
SET user1=vasya
SET user2=petya
SET cash1=1111
SET cash2=2222
SET app="C:\Program\App.exe"
SET config=app.config

if %uname%=%user1% (set %cash1% > app.config) else if (%uname%=%user2% set %cash2% > app.config)
cmd /c start /b %app%
```

Содержимое файла app.config:

```html
[Aurora]
Version.Source = "product"
ClientCheck = 0
VerifyCash =
```

Comment: Предлагаю следующий код. ищем в конфиг-файле строку с параметром VerifyCash и добавляем к строке переменную указанную параметром (процедуре или батнику). Новый конфиг-файл пишем в "app_.config" Вызов кода можно осуществить как внутреннюю процедуру, так и внешний бат-файл.

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю следующий код. Ищем в конфиг-файле строку с параметром VerifyCash и добавляем к строке переменную указанную параметром (процедуре или батнику). Новый конфиг-файл пишем в "app_.config"

```
:new-config
@echo off
if "%1" == "" exit
@del app_.config>NUL
@set str1=VerifyCash


@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%i in ('findstr /n /r ".*" app.config') do (
@set str=%%j

if not "!str!"=="" if not "!str:%str1%=!"=="!str!" @set str=!str!%1
@echo.!str!>>app_.config

)
@endlocal

@rem Скопировать новый конфиг файл в нужный каталог с необходимым именем.
@copy app_.config c:\app\app.config
```

Answer (score 0):

Daemon-5, спасибо за ваш способ. По своей задача реализовал так:

```html
@ECHO OFF

SET uname=%username%
SET user1=vasya
SET user2=petya
SET config=app.config
SET config1=app1.config
SET config2=app2.config

Setlocal

if "%uname%"=="%user1%" goto :2
if "%uname%"=="%user2%" goto :2

:1
for /f "UseBackQ tokens=1,2,3 delims=" %%G in (%config1%) do echo %%G >> %config%
start app.exe
TIMEOUT /T 15 /NOBREAK > nul rem Пауза для того, чтобы запускаемое приложение успело прочитать данные из файла app.config
del %config%
GOTO :EOF

:2
for /f "UseBackQ tokens=1,2,3 delims=" %%H in (%config2%) do echo %%H >> %config%
start app.exe
TIMEOUT /T 15 /NOBREAK > nul
del %config%
GOTO :EOF
```

Работает, но решение получилось какое-то "в лоб".
В идеале конечно хотелось, чтобы в файле аpp.config в 4й строке параметру "VerifyCash = " присваивалось соответствующее значение cash1 или cash2 в зависимости от работающего пользователя vasya или petya.
Например:
если активный пользователь vasya "VerifyCash = 1111"
и
если активный пользователь petya "VerifyCash = 2222"

Comment: Собственно ради этого я и написал код, чтобы можно было вынести создание файла в отдельную процедуру (**new-config**). Например **if "%username%"=="vasya" (call :new-config 1111) else if "%username%"=="petya" call :new-config 2222**